# Solve the limit $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{x-1}$ without l'hospital's rule.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Hey could anyone help with this? please show steps, also do not use l'hopital's rule

> $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is the derivative of the function $f(x) = \cos(\pi x/2 )$ at $x = 1$.

From the definition of the derivative,
\begin{align}
f'(1) &= \lim_{y \to 1} \, (f(y) -f(1))/(y - 1).
\end{align}
Note that $f(1) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

*littleO*'s hint should be sufficient, but here's an alternative: Do the substitution $y\leadsto x-1$, so that your limit takes the form $$\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\cos\left(\tfrac\pi2(y+1)\right)}{y}.$$ Now use the [angle-addition formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-angle_formula) and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}(x - 1) \iff \frac{\pi}{2}x = \theta + \frac{\pi}{2}$ so that $\theta \to 0$ as $x \to 1$. Then we have:
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{x - 1}
= \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\cos(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{2}{\pi}\theta}
= \frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - (\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}))}{\theta}
= -\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta )}{\theta}
= -\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from definition, the Taylor expansion of $\cos(ax)$ built around $y=b$ is given by $$\cos(ax)=\cos (a b)-a (x-b) \sin (a b)-\frac{1}{2} (x-b)^2 \left(a^2 \cos (a
   b)\right)+O\left((x-b)^3\right)$$ Make $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $b=1$ and obtain, around $x=1$ $$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)=-\frac{1}{2} \pi  (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.